# How to hide Xamarin.SideMenu?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using [Xamarin.SideMenu](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.SideMenu) and struggle with the Task to hide the side menu when a button inside the the menu is tabbed. The side menu hides automatically when you tab outside of it, but I need this functionality available programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the menu is as simple as calling `DismissViewController(true, null);` on the view Controller holding the `SideMenuManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I searched in the source code ,found when hiding side menu, it calls

```
_sideMenuManager.SideMenuTransition.HideMenuStart();
```

Just try it .